# What data type should I use to store text data?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I am making a profile system, I have a field named AboutMe in database, its datatype is text

this field may contain maximum 30,000 characters. The problem is arising is that if i am using up to  27,000 characters(or more than 4,000), they are not shown on UI, instead it truncated the content and show only few characters.
If i use 4000 or more than 4000 character, the UI shows less than 4,000 characters

I am using SQL server 2008 R2 database.

Answer (score 2):

As of SQL Server 2005, you should use `VARCHAR(MAX)` for non-Unicode text, or `NVARCHAR(MAX)` for Unicode text (using up 2 bytes per character). `TEXT` and `NTEXT` have been deprecated and **should not** be used anymore.

Those are the current datatypes, and they can be treated just like any other text / string column. All the string functions work on them just fine.

The maximum capacity for each of those column is **2 GByte** of data - that's 2 billion characters of non-Unicode or 1 billion Unicode characters.

Considering that a really long book like Tolstoj's *War and Peace* is probably 5 million characters or less (560'000 words), this would be enough space to store that book at least **200 times in Unicode** - should be plenty enough for **most** applications....

Answer (score 2):

The `text` data type is [deprecated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx), so you should use varchar(max) instead.

If by UI you mean SQL Managament Studio, it's correct that it won't show large text values. The editor has some limitations like that, for performance reasons.

When you access the data programmatically there is no such limitation. You should however be aware that large text values is sent in a separate data stream, so if you have more than one large text value per record, you have to access them in the order that you select them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ntext datatype for that.